# Problem with .htaccess, getting Internal Server Error

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, .htaccess

I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error when I try to open my website.

The content of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEnergie on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

The content of the file 000-default.conf file:

[image: 000-default.conf]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of `.htaccess` should be `RewriteEngine on` and not `RewriteEnergie on`. :)